# Distinct count to include blank values

Tags: crystal-reports

In the `Running Total Fields`, how do you set up a `Distinct Count` that includes blank values as one of your conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found a solution. It's:

```
isnull({table.column})
```

Before asking, that's what I tried, but it wasn't working. So for people like me who tried that and it didn't work, that's because you have multiple conditions in your `Running Total`, and for whatever reason it only works when you edit your syntax and place that near the top of your conditions instead of the bottom. Don't know the reason, but it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend replacing the field you're currently totaling with a new Formula. Something that doesn't ever come up blank, like:

```
If ISNULL {yourfieldhere} THEN "Blank" ELSE {yourfieldhere}
```

or if it's an empty string:

```
If {yourfieldhere}="" THEN "Blank" ELSE {yourfieldhere}
```

You can replace `"Blank"` with whatever suits you, even just an empty `" "` space or `0`. But then it's at least something distinct to be counted.

Comment: I'd prefer not to replace any values. I found a work around solution. Thanks

Comment: @PhilK The only place you'd need to replace it is inside the running total. Everywhere else it can be left alone.